# How to find out all [0-9,a-z,A-Z] from all [pre] tags, and add color for them?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find out all [0-9,a-z,A-Z] from all [pre] tags, and add color for them

Presently I only do it like this:

[image]

As you see, it just works on single [pre] tag, how can it work on all [pre] tags?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head><body>
<h3>example1</h3>  
<pre>
|      X2          T21
|-----| |----------|/|----------( Y20 )
|                |
|                |     T20
|                ------|/|----------( T21  K40 )
|
|     T20
|-----| |-----------------------( T20  K20 )
</pre>
  
<p>info..</p>
  
<h3>example2</h3>  
<pre>
|     X0           M0
|-----| |----------|/|--------------------( Y0 )
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        ---------( T0  K100 )
|     T0           T1
|-----| |----------|/|--------------------( M0 )
|                |
|      M0     |
|-----| |---------------------------------( T1  K50 )
</pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var content = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;
    var str = content;  
    var newstr = str.replace(/([+\-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?)/g, "<font color=blue>$1</font>");
    document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = newstr;
</script>
  
</body></html>
 Run code snippetReturn to post
```

I try it again used the codes below, but it doesn't work, what's wrong?

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('pre').innerHTML;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var n = x.replace(/([+\-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?)/g, "<font color=blue>$1</font>");
  x[i].innerHTML = n
}
```

Comment: Your `x` is innerHtml of tag, not array of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. Besides, you're using the `font` tag, which should be avoided in favour of CSS.

The simples solution is this, in plain JavaScript:

```
var preTags = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
for (var i = 0; i < preTags.length; i++) {
    var tag = preTags[i];
    tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.replace(/([+\-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?)/g, '<span style="color: blue;">$1</span>');
}
```

Comment: i try it ,but doesn't work on page. maybe double quotes cause confusion

Comment: "<span style="color: blue;">$1</span>"  should be "<span style='color: blue;'>$1</span>"

Comment: Yes, I changed the quotes. Hadn't realised before, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the elements array:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');

for (let i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  var str = allElements[i].innerHTML;
  var newstr = str.replace(/([+\-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?)/g, "<font color=blue>$1</font>");
  allElements[i].innerHTML = newstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate all elements with the same tag name.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/([+\-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?)/g, "<font color=blue>$1</font>");
}
```

```html
<h3>example1</h3>  
<pre>
|      X2          T21
|-----| |----------|/|----------( Y20 )
|                |
|                |     T20
|                ------|/|----------( T21  K40 )
|
|     T20
|-----| |-----------------------( T20  K20 )
</pre>
  
<p>info..</p>
  
<h3>example2</h3>  
<pre>
|     X0           M0
|-----| |----------|/|--------------------( Y0 )
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        ---------( T0  K100 )
|     T0           T1
|-----| |----------|/|--------------------( M0 )
|                |
|      M0     |
|-----| |---------------------------------( T1  K50 )
</pre>
```

Comment: IE not surport  `for (let element of document.getElementsByTagName('pre')) {` I use this htm in CHM files